# How to return count of number in sequence after validating three values from 3 different columns even though there will be matched data found?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, conditional-statements, countif

I have a range of cells in excel. How to increment numbers when meeting data validation from three different columns?

I tried using formula COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2) which creates a number sequence. But I have other data to validate from another column for it to return the correct number sequence.

First validation: count the emp no in column range A1:A5 which return a result under Hierarchy column.

[image: first validation formula looks like]

Second validation: check the % value under column L as per below level of hierarchy in which the problem comes from.
1 - 0.25
2 - 0.25
3 - 0.5
4 - 0.5
5 - 1

[image: level of hierarchy and %]

Third validation: check the type of Relation (see Relation column) that needs to check when returning number of sequence too. Below is the Relation Level table.

[image: level of relation]

I don't know on how to join these three conditions for the result to be as below.

[image: desired result]

My really problem here is on how will i get a sequence number if a person does have 3 children and should be tagged as 2,3,4 (next to spouse which is 1) then the next relation which is parent will be tagged then as next number sequence from the last count of child wherein will be 5 given that as per relation table, Parent level is 3 but it will be adjusted as per count of relations a person has. And for this specific instance, if Parent count will be 5, it still should have 0.5 EE % (see relation table level vs % hierarchy level) even though the count of number is 5. I hope this will make sense. But let me know if you have any questions.

Hope someone could help me on this coz I am not that expert when it comes to excel formula. Thank you!

Comment: Why does the hierarchy in the desired result go 4-1-2-3 and not 3-1-2-4?

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for spotting that one. Forgot to add it but I have added the third validation which from the Relation column. If you take a look in the screenshot of relation level table, you'll see on why its 4-1-2-3 and not 3-1-2-4.

Comment: But 3 for Parent won't work if there are more than two children. Wouldn't it make more sense to have Parent = 1, Spouse = 2 and the rest counts to how many children there are

Comment: That's really my problem i dont know on how and where to put my data validation (i am thinking of IF, AND formula from these three columns given that Child is second dependent from relation table but if there were more than 1 child, that should be tagged as next number sequence which is 3 and the next level of relation will be tagged as 4.  Though i understand your point, but in that way it'll messed up the EE % value as Parent is only 0.5% and re-arranging it to 1 as relation level will resulted to 0.25% as per hierarchy level which is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you should describe - within your question - what you want to achieve with ther Hierarchy-column - otherwise it is really hard to understand all the dependencies.

Comment: Yup thanks I am also trying to explain it in detailed yet simple.

Comment: @PreciousM What happens to all relations if there is no spouse? Also, about the %, how does the % affect the calculus? It looks like more is the other way, I mean, that if hierarchy is 1 or 2 then return 0,25, 3-4 return 0,5 and so on.... It looks like you only need the relation column to get the hierarchy showed in your last image

Comment: Also, please notice the hierarchy number you are searching for it's the last digit of column ID NUMBER...

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks for looking into that. I understand your point for the need of getting the hierarchy based on the relation column. Though for that one, if the relation Child or Parent (Mother or Father) got repeated, can you help me on how to still get a continuous count of number? If the Child 1 and Child 2 has no unique quality to identify? Thank you!

Comment: *If the Child 1 and Child 2 has no unique quality to identify* If there is no quality to identify them, you can't make a count to identify them. As I said, I strongly suggest to use the field IDNUMBER